# Access currently logged in user in EntityRepository

Tags: symfony

I want to create a simple blog example where users have a favourite category attached to there account. This means the can only write articles for this category. (Some of them - mostly admins -will get the opportunity to switch categories, but that's not the problem... for now ^^)

So I first created a relation between the User- and the Category entity. Everything works fine. Each user now has a main category selected.

Only thing which bothers me, is that I cant get hold of the current logged in user in the EntityType (formbuilder) and EntityRepository classes.

In my "New Post" form there are relations to other entities (e.g. Tags). I use the 'entity' formtype in the EntityType class to generate these form elements. Now i wan't to filter the tags, to only allow tags which have the same category relation as the currently logged in users category to be selectable.

I tried to use the query_builder option from the entity formtype. But as i can't get the current user object, I don't know which category he has selected. Same problem with the EntityRepository.

Now I could filter the tags already in the PostController but the problem is, that I will need this over and over again. And therefore I don't wan't to code this everytime I add something new.

I thought it would be the best to place this filter in the EntityRepository. So I can always access the findAllByCategory. But I need the user-object in there.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Have searched a lot, but either I searched for the wrong terms or no one has this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject security context in your form type defined as a service. Then in your tags field use the query builder with `$user` (current logged user) to filter tags which have the same category relation as the currently logged:

```
/** @DI\Service("form.type.post") */
class PostType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext
     */
    protected $securityContext;

    /**
     * @DI\InjectParams({"securityContext" = @DI\Inject("security.context")})
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext $context
     */
    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $user = $this->securityContext()->getToken()->getUser();

        $builder->add('tags', 'entity', array(
            'label'         => 'Tags',
            'class'         => 'Acme\HelloBundle\Entity\Tag',
            'property'      => 'name',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use($user) {
                return $er->getAllSuitableForUserChoiceQueryBuilder($user);
            },
            'multiple'      => true,
            'expanded'      => true,
    }
}
```

Filter tags into your repository:

```
class TagRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getAllSuitableForUserChoiceQueryBuilder(User $user)
    {
        // Filter tags that can be selected by a given user
    }
}
```

Comment: According to your comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709246/access-currently-logged-in-user-in-entityrepository/11709590#comment15534115_11709590
If you think that injection is not the right way, than why you propose the same? :)

Comment: @thecatontheflat I'm injecting in the form type(the right place...) not in Tag entity. You said "You can define your Entity as service" - oh no, not this.

Comment: Thanks that works. But isn't it better to add the security.context to the entityrepository? Then i would only need to add this once for every form which contains this tag-field... note: there is a little typo in your code. In the line "$this->securityContext->getToken" -> securityContext is a variable not a method

Comment: @AlexB. If you want the tag field to act the same create a `TagType` form type that inherits from `entity` and use the after mentioned security context. You can then reuse your tag field in other form types. Repositories are for data fetching only, shouldn't contain such a logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can get user object from `Security Context`

```
$user = $serviceContainer->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

**Small tip**: In case if user is not logged in - you'll have string in `$user`, otherwise - User object.

Cheers ;)

Comment: yeah i know this. but how do i get the security.context other then from within an controller?

Comment: You can define your Entity as service and inject `security.context` there

Comment: I think that injection the context in the entity is not the right way to do this thing...

Answer (score 1):

> tried to use the query_builder option from the entity formtype. But as i can't get the current user object, i don't know which category he has selected. Same problem with the EntityRepository.

As long the Category has a relation to the user, you should be able to get the User there.

For Example:

Controller

```
$someThing   = new SomeThing();
$someThing->setUser($user);
$form = $this->createForm(new someThingType(), $someThing);
```

Form

```
$someThing = $options['data'];
$user      = $someThing->getUser();
$builder->add('category', null, array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle:Cateogry',
    'query_builder' => 
        function(EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
            return $er->getCategoriesForUser($user);
        }
));
```

Repository

```
public function getCategoriesForUser($user)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $qb->leftJoin('c.user', 'u', 'with', 'u.user = :user');
    $qb->setParameter('user', $user)
    ;

    return $qb;
}
```

this is not exactly your use-case but pretty similar to it. maybe it helps you.