# Access current user in Symfony 2.1 Abstract Type

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm a bit confused about how to access the current user in Symfony 2. Currently I'm trying to display a variation of a form (AbstractType) depending on the ROLES of the current user.

A similar question has already been answered by [Gremo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220180/gremo): [Access currently logged in user in EntityRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709246/access-currently-logged-in-user-in-entityrepository)

My question is: Is there a Symfony 2 native way to access the user inside my AbstractType class without using [JMSDiExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/de/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle)? Thanks!

Here's my current code:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class Comment extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        //somehow access the current user here

        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('comment_text')
            ->add('comment_email')

        // Add more fields depending on user role

                ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Comment'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_demobundle_comment';
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I'm looking for the currently logged in user (security.context)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Into your controller, do something like this

```
$form = $this->createForm(new CommentType($this->get('security.context')
                                           ->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')), $comment);
```

Where `ROLE_ADMIN` is the role for which you want to discriminate.

Now, into your `Type` you have to retrieve it into the following way

```
private $isGranted;

public function __construct($roleFlag)
{
  $this->isGranted = $roleFlag;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  $builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('comment_text')
    ->add('comment_email');

    if($this->isGranted) {
      $builder
        ->add(....)
        ->add(....)
        [....]
        ->add(....);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the code I implemented after seeing user1326721's reply ;-)
`private $roleFlag;`

should be 

`private $isGranted;`

though

Answer (score 6):

JMSDiExtraBundle provide (among other) annotations and shortcuts in order to define services, for example form types and doctrine listeners, that is just regular services but **with particular tags**. If i recall correctly the bundle is included in a standard Symfony 2.1 release, so why not using it?

Anyway to inject the user "the old way", use constructor injection for example:

```php
class Comment extends AbstractType
{
    private $context;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $context)
    {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $loggedUser = $this->context->getToken()->getUser();

        /* ... */
    }
}
```

And define it as a service with the `form.type` tag:

```xml
<service id="form.type.comment" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Comment">
    <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
    <tag name="form.type" alias="comment" />
</service>
```

Comment: `$this->securityContext` should be `$this->context`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you inject the User as a ConstructorArgument:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new CommentType($user), $comment);
```

I'm new in Symphony so i hope this is not totaly wrong :-S

Comment: It's not totally wrong, but does not play good when your type becomes a [service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service) which in my opinion, is the way to do it right for reusable types. Anyhow, your answer is valid :)

Comment: @Matt: technically his solution is the best. Code is reusable (because the CommentType is a class) and define a service, here, isn't important. That's because, services, are useful only under two circumstance. The first is, when that service do " a lot of thing" about a specifi task. Build a form isn't one of those (formBuilder and others alredy do that). Moreover, a service will "live" only for request-timelife, so pull your conclusions

Comment: I agree that code is still reusuable as is. But I disagree with your two other comments. Services are way more useful than this. They help reduce the options you need to pass to each of your form types since you can inject dependencies direclty into the type, like the `security.context` service.  They also ease the reuse of type inside other types that embedded sub-types (like the CollectionType) and they are faster because they can be cached. Finally, instantiating type will probably be removed in Symfony 2.2. See this [PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5321) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, I implemented it like this.

Answer (score -2):

If the UserObject is part of the Comment Model you're working on with your form you'll be able to access it via:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $user = $builder->getData()->getUser();
    ....
```

Comment: This would give me the user object that has been persisted with an existing comment, no?
I'm trying to access the currently logged in user from the security context so I can use the info before showing the for for adding a **new** comment. I've updated the question.

Comment: when creating your form to add a new comment, you would inject the logged in user from the security context into the form.
Instead of access the security context from within the FormType you simply inject the user object from your controller, where you create the new instance of your form